# Implement a function to check if a linked list is a palindrom- no recursion,no stack,no reverse

Tags: java

I just write a code for this one and i didnt use any of the common solutions like stack/reverse/recusion and just wonder if this solution is a good one or not. 
algorithm:
check the nodes data from start and from end, each time i checked 2 nodes-one from start and second from end. and each time head step by one and runner is updated as a new tail.

the algorithm works fine for me and i checked many inputs just want to know why is not one of the solution options. thanks:)

```
public static boolean isAPalindrom(Node head, Node tail)
{
    int count = 0;
    Node node = head;
    Node curr = head;
    Node runner = head;

    //count = linked list size
    while (node!= null)
    {
        count++;
        node = node.next;
    }

   if(head.data != tail.data)
       return false;


   //we need size/2-1 times to check a palindrom since we check 2 nodes each time head and tail
   for(int i=0 ; i<count/2 - 1; i++)
   {
       //head is each time step by one
       curr = curr.next;
       //runner back to head each time
       runner = head;

       while(runner.next != tail)
           runner = runner.next;


       if(curr.data != runner.data)
           return false;

       //new tail to check the next time
       tail = runner;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's count/2-1? what happens with 3 nodes?

Comment: Hey Koral, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for hints on asking appropriate questions. Unfortunately this question seems too open to allow for a specific answer and will only invite opinions.

Comment: You need only one check in 3 nodes case which i checked before-head and tail.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this approach is that (unless your nodes are "doubly linked") you'll be slow.
Each comparison requires you to "run" to the new end: n+(n-1)... -> n^2/2~

Other approaches take much less time (n~) but cost a bit of space.

Edit: a small (but easy) improvement to your solution would be to start running at curr and not at the head, but the time complexity is (sadly) not going to change with this upgrade.

Comment: You're welcome, perhaps you can mark this is an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we determine a `good` algorithm by its time complexity and space complexity.

Your solution is not so `good` for time complexity. We can easily get a `O(n)` solution, while yours has a `O(n^2)`.

For space, your solution is good compared with other solution like using a stack. Your solution solve the problem `in place`, which means it costs `O(1)` space, whileas other solution usually costs `O(n)` space.

But note that, generally speaking, we care more about `time complexity` than `space complexity`

Comment: I think it's not just that normally people care more about time complexity than space complexity (and I hope whoever asked them to supply a solution did specify which parameters mattered the most) but also that (as a rule of thumb) O(n) in two dimensions is "smaller" than O(n^2) in one dimension.